React Native app not configured for iPad, big black border on iPad
I am creating a React native app specifically for an iPad and i am using vscode on Windows. My app runs fine on Expo Go but when I did a production build it didn't format for iPad it has a big black border around the whole thing and it's really zoomed in the middle:

but works fine on iPhone:

Everything I have searched and tried keeps saying to change your Xcode settings but as I said I am not using Xcode I am using vscode on Windows.
I have tried to change the Info.plist file and added this:
 <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <string>1</string> <!-- iPhone -->
        <string>2</string> <!-- iPad -->
    </array>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>

I have tablet supported in my app.json file:
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "org.name.CampConfidence",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splashscreen.png" ,
      "resizemode": "cover",
      "UIRequiresFullScreen": true
      },

I also changed my SplashScreen.storyboard file:
<device id="ipad" orientation="landscape" appearance="light"/>

I have tried changing the id to universal and that didn't do anything either.
has anyone else had this problem and fixed it? is there anyway to configure it to work with iPad without using xcode?
